# Audio clipping after amerge in FFmpeg

Tags: bash, audio, video, ffmpeg

Hoping someone out there can help me with this audio issue I'm having using FFmpeg.  I've written a bash script using FFmpeg that processes as source a broadcast quality ProRes (HQ) file with four mono tracks of audio.  Source audio is LPCM 24-bit, 48kHz signed little endian, and I am exporting the same.  Track 1 is full mix left, track 2 is full mix right, track 3 is music/FX left and track 4 is music/FX right.  The script takes the source video and trims the video asset using in and out points from a sidecar XML.  It also adds a custom slate at the head that uses a separate slate-only MOV file and is joined together via concat.  Custom text is added to the slate via the drawtext filter and, finally, audio tracks 3 and 4 are removed and tracks 1 and 2 are merged together into a single stereo interleaved track using amerge.

All of this, seemingly, works like a charm.  The problem I'm noticing occurs when I run the resulting export through our in-house QC software.  This software detects audio signal clipping at multiple points throughout the file created by FFmpeg.  When I create this exact same file via Adobe Premiere or another transcode system, our QC does not detect any clipping.  Our QC tools also do not detect any clipping in the source file.  This leads me to believe that the clipping is being introduced either by FFmpeg or by my implementation of it.  I've tried multiple additional filters within FFmpeg, including pan, amix, volume, etc., but nothing seems to help.

Anyone have any ideas?  Pasting the relevant section of my script for reference:

```
ffmpeg \
-ss "$hour":"$min":"$sec""$mil_fin" \
-t "$hour_minus":"$min_b":"$sec_b""$mil_fin_b" \
-i "$vid" \
-i "$elements_path"Slate_HD.mov \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a:0] [0:a:1] amerge=inputs=2 [stereo]; \
[1:0] [1:1] [0:0] [stereo] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]; \
[v]drawtext=enable='between(t,0,28)':fontfile="$fonts"Arial.ttf:fontsize=50:fontcolor=white\
:x=170:y=170:text='$title', \
drawtext=enable='between(t,0,28)':fontfile="$fonts"Arial.ttf:fontsize=50:fontcolor=white\
:x=170:y=170+50:text='Series $series_number Episode $episode_number', \
drawtext=enable='between(t,0,28)':fontfile="$fonts"Arial.ttf:fontsize=50:fontcolor=white\
:x=170:y=170+150:text='$transcode_date', \
yadif=0:-1:0 [o]" \
-map '[o]' -map '[a]' \
-timecode 09:59:30:00 \
-c:v prores_ks -profile:v 3 \
-c:a pcm_s24le \
-threads 3 \
"$output_name".mov
```

**Per suggestion, simplified audio only command line was run as follows:**

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov -i Slate_HD.mov -filter_complex "[0:a:0] [0:a:1] amerge=inputs=2 [stereo];[1:a][stereo]concat=n=2:a=1:v=0" -c:a pcm_s24le test_output.mov
```

**...and the log from that command line:**

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/input/test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 170739 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080, 166061 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:5(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/input/Slate_HD.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 77599 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 75783 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> amerge:in0 (graph 0)
  Stream #0:2 (pcm_s24le) -> amerge:in1 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (pcm_s16le) -> concat:in0:a0 (graph 0)
  concat (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 10-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] 264 - core 161 r3048 b86ae3c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=81 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7feade41dfc0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7feade41dfc0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
Output #0, mov, to '/output/test_output.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 0.04 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=  15.0kbits/sframe=   88 fps= 80 q=40.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.17 bitrate=1791.7kbits/frame=  133 fps= 82 q=40.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:02.98 bitrate=2110.4kbits/frame=  164 fps= 76 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:04.21 bitrate=2488.8kbits/frame=  185 fps= 70 q=40.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:05.06 bitrate=2899.0kbits/frame=  195 fps= 61 q=40.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:05.44 bitrate=3079.6kbits/frame=  206 fps= 55 q=40.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:05.89 bitrate=3557.0kbits/frame=  218 fps= 51 q=40.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:06.38 bitrate=3942.1kbits/frame=  230 fps= 47 q=40.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:06.85 bitrate=4284.1kbits/frame=  242 fps= 44 q=40.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:07.34 bitrate=4570.7kbits/frame=  251 fps= 42 q=37.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:07.70 bitrate=4627.7kbits/frame=  265 fps= 41 q=40.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:08.25 bitrate=5334.4kbits/frame=  272 fps= 39 q=40.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:08.53 bitrate=5406.8kbits/frame=  283 fps= 37 q=40.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:08.98 bitrate=5370.6kbits/frame=  296 fps= 37 q=40.0 size=    6400kB .04 bitrate=5549.0kbits/frame= 3001 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=  106530kB time=00:02:30.04 bitrate=5816.4kbits/s speed=1.07x    
video:64287kB audio:42199kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.041280%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame I:33    Avg QP:33.56  size:113497
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame P:984   Avg QP:36.20  size: 35478
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame B:1984  Avg QP:37.44  size: 13696
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] consecutive B-frames: 11.5%  0.9%  0.9% 86.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb I  I16..4:  3.4% 86.8%  9.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb P  I16..4:  1.6% 13.7%  0.7%  P16..4: 44.3%  8.5%  7.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  1.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 47.6%  2.4%  0.3%  direct: 1.3%  skip:47.3%  L0:47.0% L1:51.3% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] 8x8 transform intra:85.9% inter:88.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 67.9% 73.8% 13.9% inter: 20.8% 21.6% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 48% 15%  4% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 11% 27%  6%  7%  7%  7%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 15% 14%  7%  9%  9%  8%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 12% 24%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref P L0: 69.1% 21.7%  9.2%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref B L0: 87.2% 10.4%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] kb/s:4387.16
WU:~ user$ 
ffmpeg version 4.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.2_3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.2 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.3 : mono
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.4 : mono
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/input/test.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 170739 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080, 166061 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:4(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, mono, s32 (24 bit), 1152 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #0:5(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74) (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/input/Slate_HD.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:30.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 77599 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: prores (HQ) (apch / 0x68637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 75783 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      encoder         : Apple ProRes 422 HQ
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
    Stream #1:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-03-22T17:23:16.000000Z
      handler_name    : Time Code Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (pcm_s24le) -> amerge:in0 (graph 0)
  Stream #0:2 (pcm_s24le) -> amerge:in1 (graph 0)
  Stream #1:1 (pcm_s16le) -> concat:in0:a0 (graph 0)
  concat (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (pcm_s24le)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (prores (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] profile High 4:2:2, level 4.0, 4:2:2, 10-bit
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] 264 - core 161 r3048 b86ae3c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2021 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=81 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7feade41dfc0] No channel layout for input 1
[Parsed_amerge_0 @ 0x7feade41dfc0] Input channel layouts overlap: output layout will be determined by the number of distinct input channels
Output #0, mov, to '/output/test_output.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s24le (in24 / 0x34326E69), 48000 Hz, stereo, s32, 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 pcm_s24le
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(top coded first (swapped)), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 0.04 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-04-22T18:58:58.000000Z
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   47 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.02 bitrate=  15.0kbits/sframe=   88 fps= 80 q=40.0 size=     256kB time=00:00:01.17 bitrate=1791.7kbits/frame=  133 fps= 82 q=40.0 size=     768kB time=00:00:02.98 bitrate=2110.4kbits/frame=  164 fps= 76 q=40.0 size=    1280kB time=00:00:04.21 bitrate=2488.8kbits/frame=  185 fps= 70 q=40.0 size=    1792kB time=00:00:05.06 bitrate=2899.0kbits/frame=  195 fps= 61 q=40.0 size=    2048kB time=00:00:05.44 bitrate=3079.6kbits/frame=  206 fps= 55 q=40.0 size=    2560kB time=00:00:05.89 bitrate=3557.0kbits/frame=  218 fps= 51 q=40.0 size=    3072kB time=00:00:06.38 bitrate=3942.1kbits/frame=  230 fps= 47 q=40.0 size=    3584kB time=00:00:06.85 bitrate=4284.1kbits/frame=  242 fps= 44 q=40.0 size=    4096kB time=00:00:07.34 bitrate=4570.7kbits/frame=  251 fps= 42 q=37.0 size=    4352kB time=00:00:07.70 bitrate=4627.7kbits/frame=  265 fps= 41 q=40.0 size=    5376kB time=00:00:08.25 bitrate=5334.4kbits/frame=  272 fps= 39 q=40.0 size=    5632kB time=00:00:08.53 bitrate=5406.8kbits/frame=  283 fps= 37 q=40.0 size=    5888kB time=00:00:08.98 bitrate=5370.6kbits/frame=  296 fps= 37 q=40.0 size=    6400kB .04 bitrate=5549.0kbits/frame= 3001 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=  106530kB time=00:02:30.04 bitrate=5816.4kbits/s speed=1.07x    
video:64287kB audio:42199kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.041280%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame I:33    Avg QP:33.56  size:113497
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame P:984   Avg QP:36.20  size: 35478
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] frame B:1984  Avg QP:37.44  size: 13696
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] consecutive B-frames: 11.5%  0.9%  0.9% 86.8%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb I  I16..4:  3.4% 86.8%  9.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb P  I16..4:  1.6% 13.7%  0.7%  P16..4: 44.3%  8.5%  7.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  1.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 47.6%  2.4%  0.3%  direct: 1.3%  skip:47.3%  L0:47.0% L1:51.3% BI: 1.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] 8x8 transform intra:85.9% inter:88.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 67.9% 73.8% 13.9% inter: 20.8% 21.6% 0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i16 v,h,dc,p: 48% 15%  4% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 11% 27%  6%  7%  7%  7%  8%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 15% 14%  7%  9%  9%  8%  6%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 12% 24%  7%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.1% UV:0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref P L0: 69.1% 21.7%  9.2%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref B L0: 87.2% 10.4%  2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] ref B L1: 94.9%  5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7feadf81a600] kb/s:4387.16
WU:~ user$
```

Comment: Simplify the issue by omitting anything not required to duplicate the issue: including the video, video filters, and bash stuff. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then show your unscripted simplified command, something like `ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[0:a:0] [0:a:1] amerge=inputs=2 [stereo];[1:a][stereo]concat=n=2:a=1:v=0" c:a pcm_s24le output.mov`, and the complete log.

Comment: How do I post the complete log?  It is over 30,000 characters in length, and I don't see any way to add it as an attachement.

Comment: yeah, but it won't let me post it due to to too many characters.

Comment: Trim the majority of any repeating stuff or use a pastebin site and provide the link.

Comment: Does the clipping occur with `ffmpeg -i input0 -filter_complex "[0:a:0] [0:a:1] amerge=inputs=2 -c:a pcm_s24le amerge.mov` or `ffmpeg -i input1 -map 0:a:0 -c:a pcm_s24le encode.mov` or `ffmpeg -i input1 -map 0:a:0 -c copy copy.mov`? Also, consider updating your ffmpeg to git (preferred) or version 4.4 ([download](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) or use [homebrew](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS#ffmpegthroughHomebrew).

Comment: I tried running all three of these simplified commands, and clipping does not occur with any of them.  Wouldn't this point to there being something about the concat with the slate MOV file?  There is an audio track muxed with the slate, however it is completely silent.  Still not sure how that would be affecting the signal of the main video file.